# Ajax is not working in Cakephp 2.2.3

Tags: ajax, cakephp-2.2

I want to implement Ajax on ContactUs form, here is my code.
Controller:

```
class ContactsController extends AppController {

public $layout = 'default';
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Paginator','Js');
public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function index(){
    if(!empty($this->data)){
        if($this->Contact->save($this->data)){
            if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
                $this->render('success','ajax');
            } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Message sent');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

View file

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery', FALSE); ?>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>

    <?php
            echo $this->Form->create();
            echo $this->Form->input('name',array('id'=>'name'));
            echo $this->Form->input('email',array('id'=>'email'));
            echo $this->Form->input('message',array('id'=>'message'));
            echo $this->Js->submit('Send',array(
                'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
                'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeout'),
                'update'=>'#success'
            ));
            echo $this->Form->end();                
            ?>                
<div id="sending" style=" display: none;background-color: #90ee90;">Sending...</div>
```

in view/layouts/ajax.ctp file contain:

```
<?php //echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

I have tried with both of these. And default.ctp layout contains in head section:

```
echo $scripts_for_layout;
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('cache'=>TRUE));
```

in source file jquery is included but PHPStorm shows error in jquery file, and firebug shows[image: firebug shows]

hope everything will be clear, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Oldskool please help me if you are here.

Answer (score 0):

ou should disable the buffer on the `before` and `success` callback.

```
echo $this->Js->submit('Send',array(
    'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false)),
    'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false)),
    'update'=>'#success'
));
```

EDIT:
The typo could cause this issue also: `'fadeout'` instead of `'fadeOut'`.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same problem.  I see you were using the Cakephp tutorial by Andrew Perkins (I am using the exact same one so my code is identical) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQ71psonQx0

I believe the problem is that he made this video tutorial based on Cakephp 1.3.  The syntax has changed a lot in 2.0.  I haven't figured out how to get it working in 2.2.3 yet either but I think that this is the reason.

Comment: No I am not following any tutorial, I am just using twitter bootstrap.